# Unable to install Express (of Node.js) in Android Termux using sdcard0 as directory

Tags: termux

I'm unable to install Express in Android Termux. I have the latest Node.js installed.

It is working perfectly when I use Private storage, but I'm using `cd /storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/` and getting a **permission denied** error. I saw the word **symlink** repeatedly in the terminal's error message.

Here's what I saw after commanding `npm install express --save`:

```
$ npm install express --save
npm WARN test-lab@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test-lab@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/3/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/3/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/3/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/3/node_modules/.bin/mime' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../mime/cli.js\' -> \'/storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/3/node_modules/.bin/mime\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/sdcard0/NodeJS/Test/3/node_modules/.bin/mime',
npm ERR!   parent: 'test-lab' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2018-05-29T13_09_20_748Z-debug.log
```

Is it really possible to install Express while current storage is something like `/storage/sdcard0/...`?

Comment: Related: [Insufficent rights for npm install in Termux on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221609/218526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is **No**, not even with root.

Android uses FUSE (Filesystem in USErspace), which has symbolic links **disabled**. Since Node needs to setup symlinks, it's impossible to install it onto the SD card (or whatever internal storage where you store your photos, downloads, etc.). You can only install it into Termux's directory, which is `/data/data/com.termux/files`.

Comment: I've already installed nodejs successfully. The problem is that I'm unable to install a nodejs module or package or plugin or whatever it is called. I was thinking of saving the app.js, package.json and the express files into a directory in sdcard0 or sdcard1.

Comment: Are you saying I can't save files (of Express) to sdcard ?

Comment: @user9850863 You can't install that Node module onto the SD card. But yeah, Node.js itself is already set up in Termux's directories.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: @user9850863 I'm honored. But if you only want to access Termux's files, you can copy them in/out to SD card with Termux. Then you can use an arbitrary file manager, without affecting the local copy that Termux holds.

Comment: Cloudcmd is a Termux package which creates a server of Web (nodejs) based file manager. I think, that using it will be a more greater idea than copying App-Private files to sdcard, editing them and copy pasting it to the old hidden directory. What do you think?

Comment: @user9850863 Well, I'm not a professional developer so I don't know a large variety of softwares. If it is so, it's surely better than copying in & out.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with this:

1. Install Termux:API ([Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.api)).
2. In Termux shell: `apt install termux-api`

That's all. https://www.npmjs.com/package/termux

Comment: How? Just installing it ?