# Insufficent rights for npm install in Termux on Android

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, permissions, termux

I'm trying to install a `Node.js` module in a folder, for example, `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/documents/projects/code/js/test-npm`, from Termux on rooted Android 6 running `npm install`. Installation starts, but never succeeds, throwing errors and warnings like `npm ERR! cb() never called!` and `WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime`.

Which permissions should I grant to `npm` and how?

**Update 1:** tried running `npm install` in `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/projects/code/js/test-npm`, got the same errors. Termux has Storage access permission in Android installed apps manager.

Comment: Related: [Unable to install express ( of node.js) in Android termux using sdcard0 as directory](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196448/218526)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime`** indicates that `futime` syscall (used to change file last access and modification times) fails with error: `EPERM`. From `utime` manpage <sup>[1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimes.2.html)</sup>:

> **EPERM**  ... the caller's effective UID does not match the owner of the file ...

That seems to be the reason of failure. You are using path: `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/` which is actually `/sdcard/` <sup>[2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218374/218526)</sup> (symlink to `/storage/emulated/0/`). It's not an actual filesystem but an emulated <sup>[3](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)</sup> view of underlying filesystem (`ext4` or `f2fs`). It has fixed permissions and doesn't support many features of Linux filesystems including symlinks and `ioctls` like `FS_IOC_FIEMAP` <sup>[4](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/218526)</sup>.

Due to fixed permissions all directories and files in `/sdcard/` are always owned by user `root` (UID `0`). So while trying to change file's timestamp, `Operation not permitted` is returned. `touch` command however uses `utimensat` <sup>[5](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209243/218526)</sup> which has different permissions requirements.

So to avoid this problem, you should not use emulated filesystem. Termux `$HOME` directory is on `ext4` or `f2fs`, so it's a good place to save files. Use e.g. `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/npm-test` directory.

From comments:

> But is it possible to somehow create a link inside `$HOME` to another location, which will grant all the rights that Termux has for `$HOME` for all the subfolders of this distant location?

No it's not possible on non-rooted phone. Apps can write only to their private directories in internal storage (which is `/data/data/com.termux` for Termux) and in shared storage (`/sdcard/Android/data/com.termux`). Apps with `Storage` permission granted can read and write to whole `/sdcard/`. There is no other place on device where apps can save files <sup>[6](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)</sup>. With SELinux `disabled` or `permissive`, it's possible to write to a sub-directory created (with `adb shell`) in `/data/local/tmp`, but it's not intended use of this directory.

---

**LINKS:**

<sup>[1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimes.2.html)</sup> `utime` manpage
<sup>[2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218374/218526)</sup> How do I access `$HOME/storage` outside of Termux (with a file explorer)?
<sup>[3](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)</sup> What is `/storage/emulated/0/`?
<sup>[4](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/218526)</sup> How can I make a symlink inside `/storage/emulated/0`?
<sup>[5](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209243/218526)</sup> How to change the modified date of a file without root?
<sup>[6](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)</sup> Where Android apps store data?